# Angular4/Typescript/Bootstrap-can't compile

Tags: angular, typescript

I get the following error:

> ERROR in multi ./node-modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 
>       ./src/styles.css
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '/Users/hansdeschinkel/VSCode/Resto/node-modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
>   in
>   '/Users/hansdeschinkel/VSCode/Resto/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'

```
"styles": [
    "../node-modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

I have saved bootstrap 3.3.7 in my `node_modules`.
I have also added it to my `angular/cli.json` folder:
I am using VSCode

Comment: Can you put the angular-cli.json code here as well? The problem is styles expect a path which is relative to index.html

Comment: are you sure that bootstrap package is there in `node_modules` folder

Answer (score 3):

If your `styels.css` in src folder and `bootstrap.min.css` in node_modules folder then change your code as shown below :

```
styles: [
       'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
       'src/styles.css'
]
```

In angular-cli to render css file give absolute path not relative path.

Answer (score 0):

**For Angular 6**

```
   "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    ],
    "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the path from

```
    "styles": [
    "../node-modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

to

```
    "styles": [
    "/node-modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```